# How can I create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, multi-signature

Can somebody help me with step-by-step list of how to create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this other question http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/how-does-one-make-multisignature-transactions-with-the-bitcoin-client doesn't appear to be a duplicate because it relates to the Bitcoin client app

Comment: Do you mean create the raw transaction, or do you just mean that you'd like to send such a transaction? If the former, then look into OP_CHECKMULTISIG and BIP-11; if the latter, then you may want to use an online wallet such as blockchain.info, which I believe handles this.

Comment: It's been a year since this was asked. What gives? See also https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=195168.0

Comment: See also - https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23889/how-do-i-create-a-2-of-3-multisig-address-using-bitcoind

Comment: To build a multisig transaction, the easiest API I know of:
http://dev.blockcypher.com/#multisig

Answer (score 14):

Actually, both receiving funds at and spending funds from a multi-sig address is already supported.

You can find the code to do so, plus comments, by Gavin:

[TwoOfThree.sh](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071)

Answer (score 13):

It seems some partial implementation exists. [Quoting Gavin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=82213.msg906833#msg906833):

#### Generate a multisig address:

1. Gather (or generate) 3 bitcoin addresses, on whichever machines will be participating, using getnewaddress or getaccountaddress  RPC commands (or copy and paste from the GUI).
2. Get their public keys using the `validateaddress` RPC command 3 times.
3. Then create a 2-of-3 multisig address using `addmultisigaddress`; e.g.

   > bitcoind addmultisigaddress 2 '["044322868cb17d64dcc22185ae2d4493111d73244c3668f8ac79ecc79c0ba8d30a6756d0fa20157 709af3281cc721c7f53321a8cabda29b77900b7e4fe0174b114","..second pubkey..","..third pubkey.."]'

`addmultisigaddress` returns the multisignature address. Be a little careful, the public keys are raw hexadecimal and don't contain checksums like bitcoin addresses do. You can then send funds into that 2-of-3 transaction using the normal sendtoaddress/sendmany RPC commands, or the GUI (or anything that's been updated to recognize multisig addresses).

#### Spend from a multisig address:

This isn't implemented yet (RPC calls mechanism). You could gather up all addresses into one wallet, and then you would be able to spend the funds.

**Update March 2014**

Multisig is still hard. I believe the [SX library](https://github.com/spesmilo/sx#multisignature-n-m-transactions) is an easy tool (by people like Vitalik Buterin and Amir Taaki) for working with multisig, but I haven't tested that myself.

Comment: Multisig is no longer hard. See my new answer below

Answer (score 4):

A m-of-n multisig address is created as follows:

1. Gather all `n` public keys.
   **e.g.** `3-of-3`
   `03730a151f545f5dcdb1c6d99fb1251f5c70f216f39ba2681bcf10db16bd582e67`, `03a9bb9d28dfcd2e58ca7b3fa39f4051a6496fc7928f993f1758aeff7c0fee0f03`, `03a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd`
2. Create the multisig script
   `OP_m <bytes-in-Pubkey1> <pubKey1> ... OP_n OP_CHECKMULTISIG`
   **e.g.** `532103730a151f545f5dcdb1c6d99fb1251f5c70f216f39ba2681bcf10db16bd582e672103a9bb9d28dfcd2e58ca7b3fa39f4051a6496fc7928f993f1758aeff7c0fee0f032103a34b99f22c790c4e36b2b3c2c35a36db06226e41c692fc82b8b56ac1c540c5bd53ae`
3. Hash the script `HASH160(<script>)`
   **e.g.**
   `8b58c2f47cd3000e42c82138f7678dc978bc109a`
4. Append `0x05` for `P2SH` address on mainnet: `05<scriptHash>`
   **e.g.**
   `058b58c2f47cd3000e42c82138f7678dc978bc109a`
5. Apply Base58Check: `BASE58CHECK(05<scriptHash>)`
   **e.g.**
   `3EPpBU7fXq1PfG6JkLnJNUUmEGcSr9rdmh`

You can send bitcoin to this address, but to spend from it, you must provide the scriptSig: `0 <sigM> ... <script>` where `<sigM>` is signed from each of the `m` private keys.

See [Bitcoin Wiki - Script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) for opcodes, [Bitcoin Wiki - Address Prefixes,](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes) and [Bitcoin Wiki - Transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-Script-Hash) for multisig `P2SH` script format.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction is with Coinb.in.

1. If necessary, create 3 key pairs using the "New Address" drop down command.
2. Use the "New Multisig Address" together with the 3 public keys to create a 2-of-3 address.
3. Fund the address with bitcoin.
4. Create a new transaction by pasting in the "redeem script" from step 3, defining the receiving addresses and amounts. (All unspent inputs not assigned to a receiving address will be used as transaction fees. If change is desired include that in a new output address by clicking the "+".)
5. Sign the transaction by one of the private keys, then sign that transaction with another of the private keys.
6. Broadcast the transaction to the network.

Comment: I made a video documenting these steps here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUSVmLegj8k