# What clients support escrow transactions apart from Blockchain's MyWallet?

Tags: multi-signature, escrow

By escrow transactions I mean basic 2 of 3 multi-signature transaction like here https://blockchain.info/wallet/escrow

Are there any other bitocoin clients where I can do this?

Comment: Note that MyWallet does not currently seem to support escrow transactions. Whilst the documentation you have linked to still exists, I cannot seem to initiate any escrow transactions on MyWallet, and I believe I've seen some statement to the effect that it was removed because it caused too much confusion.

Comment: How important is this feature for you? The main reason I haven't written a Bitcoin client myself yet is my impression that the market was saturated with existing solutions. But the apparent lack of good options makes me wonder if I should reconsider...

Answer (score 3):

[Electrum](http://electrum.org) allows to escrow transaction but requires you to use the command line interface.

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7211362) explaining how to do it.

Comment: The same appears to be true for the reference client (see ryepdx's answer). But in either case it seems rather spartanic, more like using an API (and programming a bit oneself!) than what I'd expect in user experience even from a non-GUI client. Is there any client that has proper support for it, with something that could be called a user experience rather than being a feed-the-output-back-in-several times programming-like exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options available to you.  I am not associated with any of these sites and would recommend you do your research before proceeding with any of them.  Providing any said research to other readers would be helpful for the community.

BTCrow (btcrow.com/‎)

BitMit (https://www.bitmit.net/)

BitCoin Escrow (http://thebitcoinescrow.com/)

FlipBit (http://flipbit.com/)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a **client** which can do mutlisig transactions for escrow, without any specific thirdparty escrow service.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a duplicate of [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/how-can-i-create-a-multi-signature-2-of-3-transaction), so I'm not marking it as such, but I think that question *does* answer yours. In a nutshell, the Bitcoin reference client can do this. You have to use the command line or JSON-RPC, though. Gavin Andresen [wrote a script](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071) for it.