# Seeking specific advice on three-party/escrow-type transactions

Tags: wallet, escrow, shared

I'm a professional mediator just learning about bitcoins, and I have a specific question.  I have been asked by someone if I am able to be the "third party" for a Bitcoin transaction.

In other words, Party A has X Bitcoins, he wants to sell them to party B, the X bitcoins are placed into a shared "escrow" wallet with the signatures of myself, party A, and party B. After the cash has exchanged hands (or not), any two of us (A, B, or me) can authorize the funds in the escrow wallet to be transmitted to its proper final destination.

How do I specifically do that? I mean specific instructions?  I have accounts at Coinbase, Blockchain, my own Bitcoin-QT client on Windows, and others. What's my best approach to this?

Comment: This is a douplicate of [How can I create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/what-clients-support-escrow-transactions-apart-from-blockchains-mywallet). Summary: Not even MyWallet at Blockchain.info currently supports it. All known options seem to require extensive use of the command-line, which I would not recommend as I consider that error-prone and overcomplicated. I'm starting to think I should write a software solution for this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/how-can-i-create-a-multi-signature-2-of-3-transaction)

Comment: I seem to have gotten links mixed up. The first question I wanted to point out was actually [What clients support escrow transactions apart from Blockchain's MyWallet?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/what-clients-support-escrow-transactions-apart-from-blockchains-mywallet). My first comment links to this question, but labelled it incorrectly.