# Multi signature wallet I'll know the private key

Tags: private-key, public-key, multi-signature

So my situation is I have to create a multi-signature address for our business (was going to do something like this: https://github.com/anders94/bitcoin-2-of-3-multisig).

My question is if I make it then wont I already know their keys as its possible I could just copy and paste them before handing / sending them over.

Is there a better way to do this so I would never see the private key? Were doing it on our bitcoind server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a multi signature 2-of-3 transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/how-can-i-create-a-multi-signature-2-of-3-transaction)

Comment: And no, you won't know the other participants private keys. You will only exchange your public key with the other participants.

Comment: But without logging into the server (they don't know linux) then how would they even create their own? I would have to do it for them is my point. We can't use a 3rd party service btw just bitcoind on our server.

Comment: Maybe I can convince them to setup their own electrum account or something but I dont know if they will. They want it all on the server.

Comment: Yeah, I mean what is the point of the multi-sig wallet, if you already know all the private keys and can spend the funds without the others consent.

Comment: You can try to "look away" if the private key pop-up somewhere during the process, the public keys are the essential part. There is no way you are going to remember the private keys without actively trying.

Comment: @MarcAlexander The whole point of multisig is that you never need to bring all private key material to a single system. You just give the (non-signed) transaction to each signer, they each produce their own signature, and then you combine the signatures to create a single valid transaction.

Comment: Thanks thats the answer I was looking for. They wanted it so not one person can withdraw bitcoin out of our company wallet. Which means I'm going to have to educate them on how to use a wallet that allows them to access their private key (i.e. not gemini or a service like that).