# Does blockchain.info retain the wallet password in client-side memory?

Tags: blockchain.info, javascript

When you log into blockchain.info - you enter the password on the client side.

Does the password remain stored in a local javascript variable on the client side after the login process is over?

If yes, does that count as real a security risk? What kind of attack vectors does that open you to?

If not, how else does the wallet update the server side state?

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/how-secure-is-blockchain-info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that it must have, because it updates the server after any modifying operation is made, without asking for a password.

That is [DannyHamilton claims as well](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg5515607#msg5515607). [See also](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg5605885#msg5605885).