# What are the standard formats of transaction outputs?

Tags: segregated-witness, utxo, transaction-input, output, standard

A transaction output can have the type

- Pay to public key hash, P2PKH, where the ScriptPubKey field has the format:

  76 a9 14 <20-byte hash of pubkey> 88 ac
- Pay to script hash, P2SH, used for e.g. multisig:

  a9 14 <20-byte hash of script> 87

There is also something called P2WPKH and P2WSH. Can you show me how these outputs are formatted, and are there any more possible output formats than these four?

Comment: the SegWit formats: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Segregated_Witness, or here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/. And then there was in early times "pay to public key", and the old "multisig" types (non-P2SH). Not sure if they are still valid today.

Comment: I didn't know the pay to public key format. Interesting! I had heard about the "multisig" type but never encountered it or a description of it.

Comment: I think it was called bare multisig. And was BIP0011. A quick search in the forum: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29708/multi-signature-and-pay-to-script-hash-vs-pay-to-pub-key-hash/29819#29819

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there are 5 different standard non-SegWit transaction types, and 4 SegWit ones.

Non-SegWit:

**Pay to public key (P2PK)**

```
PUSH (1 byte) + <compressed/uncompressed_pk> (33/65 bytes) + OP_CHECKSIG (1 byte)
```

**Pay to public key hash (P2PKH)**

```
OP_DUP (1 byte) + OP_HASH160 (1 byte) + PUSH (1 byte) + <hash_160(PK)> (20 bytes) + OP_EQUALVERIFY (1 byte) + OP_CHECKSIG (1 byte)
```

**Multisig (P2MS)**

```
<number_of_PKs> (1 byte) PUSH (1 byte) <PK_0> (33/65 bytes) PUSH (1 byte) <PK_1> (33/65 bytes)  ... PUSH (1 byte) <PK_n-1> (33/65 bytes) OP_CHECKMULTISIG (1 byte)
```

P2MS allow up to 15-15 scripts, however only up to 3-3 are standard.

**Pay to script hash (P2SH)**

```
OP_HASH160 (1 byte) + PUSH (1 byte) + <hash160(redeem_script)> (20 bytes) + OP_EQUAL (1 byte)
```

**OP_Return**

```
OP_RETURN (1 byte) PUSH (1 byte) <0 to 83 bytes of data>
```

SegWit:

Regarding segwit types, there are two non-native and two native ones.

**Native Pay to witness public key hash (P2WPKH)**

```
OP_0 (1 byte) PUSH (1 byte) <hash 160(PK*)> (20 bytes)
```

**Native Pay to witness script hash (P2WSH)**

```
OP_0 (1 byte) PUSH (1 byte) <script_hash> (32 bytes)
```

**Pay to witness public key hash encapsulated in a pay to script hash (P2SH-P2WPKH)**

The redeem script follows the same structure than native P2WPKH:

`redeem_script = OP_0 (1 byte) PUSH (1 byte) <hash_160(PK*)> (20 bytes)`

While the external structure of the script (`scriptPubKey`) is as any other P2SH:

```
OP_HASH160 (1 byte) + PUSH (1 byte) + <hash_160(redeeem_script)> (20 bytes) + OP_EQUAL (1 byte)
```

**Pay to witness script hash encapsulated in a pay to script hash (P2SH-P2WSH)**

The redeem script follows the same structure than native P2WSH:

`redeem_script = OP_0 (1 byte) PUSH (1 byte) <script_hash> (32 bytes)`

While the external structure of the script (`scriptPubKey`) is as any other P2SH:

```
OP_HASH160 (1 byte) + PUSH (1 byte) + <hash_160(redeeem_script)> (20 bytes) + OP_EQUAL (1 byte)
```

*In P2WPKH scripts the hash 160 should correspond to a compressed public key, otherwise the funds will be lost.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand your last sentence: "Non-native pay to witness script hash encapsulated in a pay to script hash (P2SH-P2WPKH) have the same structure." Can you elaborate on that? As far as I understood, non-native segwit outputs are indistinguishable from P2SH-outputs.

Comment: What I ment is that in P2SH-P2WPKH the redeem script follows the structure of the native P2WPKH and in the P2SH-P2WSH the redeem script follows the structure of the native P2WSH. I'll edit it for clarification.

Comment: Reviewing the answer I realized that the OP_Return script was not up to date. The max amount of data to be pushed is 83 bytes since Bitcoin Core 0.12. I've updated the answer to correct it.

Comment: Could this answer be updated with P2TR outputs?