# P2SH that pays out only to a certain Bitcoin address?

Tags: p2sh

Is it possible to create a type of redemption script that when the correct number of signatures are collected pays out to a pre-defined address ?

Comment: And who would be able to sign? If anyone can sign, this is trivial to game. Otherwise it is [multisig](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3729/5406)?

Comment: Yes it would be multi sig. Basically a multi sig address that only pays out to a pre-determined bitcoin address.

This would be useful as a secure bitcoin vault. Even if the key holders collude. The destination can't be changed. You could then create a hierarchy of wallets with different approval levels.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had overread the "pre-defined address" part. Carry on. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible, but with a subtle difference to how OP suggests.

OP seems to want: funds are first signed off by the multisig address, then a transaction is broadcast moving the funds to [destination].

It's not possible for a destination script to stipulate where the funds can end up. A new opcode could introduce that feature, but we can do this a different way.

I would argue this no weaker than having a transaction between the two destinations (as OP envisioned). In either case the multisig participants could hold the funds to ransom before the end user can move them.

```
Multisig: 2 [pubkey1] [pubkey2] 3 CHECKMULTISIG
Destination: DUP HASH160 [hash] EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG
```

Since we cannot lock funds so they are released to a certain destination, we just merge the two scripts, allowing predefined party to take control only when the multisig is solved. He would propose a spend to the others, they sign, then he signs (it can be done in any order)

The scriptPubKey (or P2SH script) would then look like this:

```
 2 [pubkey1] [pubkey2] 3 CHECKSIG DUP HASH160 [hash] EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG
```

And the scriptSig:

```
 [sig1] [sig2] [sigA] [pubkeyA]
```

Comment: Re ransom/theft: In the predetermined address case, they would refuse to sign release unless they are paid 1BTC. In my case, they would only sign a transaction if x% goes to their address.