# Release A Bitcoin From Multi Sig Address?

Tags: transactions, multi-signature

I just made a multi sig address from 3 address bitcoin and the result from that is 3Gf18oGoTaNCW38dVKe2ygNpUvUJmg6TY9

and i want to know how i can release the bitcoin ?

Comment: What client software are you using?

Comment: I get the addy from online wallet

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't very helpful.  **Which** online wallet?  Can you give more details about how you created the multisig address?

Comment: i try to make a multi sig addresa from here https://coinb.in/multisig/ and the addy from here https://coinb.in/#newAddress 

i add around 3 Public keys  into multisig  and then the result addy is 3258WPQNy7FL1uHCyLwSjG35zQVtePGsjL 

and if my friend send me bitcoin from that addy will the balance show in other addy that i combine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you made the multisig address through bitcoind? if you have all the private keys related to that multisigned address added and in your wallet it should be automatically included in your balance and spent.

Quote from Gavin Anderson ([How does one make multisignature transactions with the bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/how-does-one-make-multisignature-transactions-with-the-bitcoin-client))
First answer there

*spending of multisignature transactions-- if all of the private keys required to spend a multisignature transaction are in the wallet, then those coins are added to the wallet's total bitcoin balance and that transaction will be spent if the normal coin-selection code decides to use them for a spending transaction.*

if you require instructions for a specific wallet or a middle-agent website then it would be useful if you mention what exactly it is.